# Is there any methods to insert more jooq like way?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, insert, jooq

I have Postgresql insert statement like this..

```sql
INSERT INTO users (user_id, pswd, name, email, email_use_yn)
VALUES (#{userId}, ENCODE(digest(#{newPswd}, 'sha256'), 'HEX'), #{name}, #{email}, 
COALESCE(IFCOND(#{email} IS NULL, 'N'::char, #{emailUseYn}::char), 'N'))
```

here IFCOND is user defined function like mysql IF function.
and insert can be done by jooq

```java
dsl.insertInto(USERS, 
            USERS.USER_ID, USERS.PSWD, USERS.NAME, USERS.EMAIL, USERS.EMAIL_USE_YN)
    .values(user.getUserId(), 
            hex(SHA256(user.getPswd())), 
            user.getName(), 
            user.getEmail(),
            user.getEmail() == null ? "N" : 
                (user.getEmailUseYn() == null ? "N" : user.getEmailUseYn()))
    .execute();
```

but i'm curious about it can be done more jooq like way?
is there any?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming by "not-so-jOOQ-like", you mean the fact that you used conditional operators in Java, rather than a SQL `CASE` expression. Well, then, just use [the SQL `CASE` expression with jOOQ](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/case-expressions/).

This SQL fragment:

```sql
COALESCE(IFCOND(#{email} IS NULL, 'N'::char, #{emailUseYn}::char), 'N'))
```

Could be written as such:

```java
coalesce(
    choose().when(val(user.getEmail()).isNull(), inline("N"))
            .otherwise(user.getEmailUseYn()), 
    inline("N")
);
```